# GCP Datastore render in JINJA2 shows also the complete key

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-datastore, jinja2

So I pass the result from `ds_data = list(query.fetch())` to JINJA2:

`return render_template('index.html',images=ds_data)`

To python this can be iterated as list with no problems but for JINJA2:

`data-json="{{image|safe}}"`

instead of having some dict: `'{}'` in HTML, I have the also complete key:

```
data-json="<Entity('kind', 'id') {'someDictKey': 'value', 'someDictKey': 'value'}>"
```

Hm, any ideas how can I remove the Entity's key in python, or render it correctly in JINJA2?

Template Snippet:

```
{% block content %}
{% if images is defined %}
<div class="main-content" id="main-content">
...
{% for image in images %}
<tbody id="tbody{{ image['key'] }}" data-json="{{ image  }}">
</tbody>
{% endfor %}
...
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Could you provide the template snippet that accesses the variable?

Answer (score 1):

You'll actually have to convert your data to a json string.  E.g. `json.dumps(image)`.  Specifically, you can see you'll need to cast `image` to a dict to get the map you want (https://googleapis.dev/python/datastore/latest/entities.html).

Comment: thank you! I was hopping I missed something. I've posted the complete solution  i've done last night

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did last night after all:

```
@app.template_filter('parse_entity_list')
def parse_filter(item):
    # Recompose DS object to list of dicts
    a = json.dumps(item)
    return a


app.jinja_env.filters['parse_entity_list'] = parse_filter
```

JINJA2 side:

`<tbody id="tbody{{ image['key'] }}" data-json="{{ image | parse_entity_list }}">`